# OpenMP and sections

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

i have the following code :

```
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2) {
  #pragma omp section
   Function_1;
   #pragma omp section
   Function_2;
}
```

but within the Function_1 and Function_2, i have a parallel for but just one thread run it.
So, how run the Function_1 and Function_2 in parallel and run several threads within these functions?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having one `parallel` region inside another is called nesting. By default nested regions are inactive, which means that they execute serially. In order to make them active, you can:

- set the environment variable `OMP_NESTED` to `true`
- insert the following call before the enclosing `parallel` region: `omp_set_nested(1);`

One can also limit the number of levels, where nested parallelism works, by:

- setting the environment variable `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` to `num`, or
- calling `omp_set_max_active_levels(num);`

where `num` is the desired maximum active level, e.g. a value of `3` would render all `parallel` regions, nested more than `3` levels deep, inactive.